# Немного неточный рекламный баннер Ru.SO

Tags: дефект, статус-запланировано

Захожу на сайт и вижу рекламный баннер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ага, здорово, а я как раз хочу спросить:

- Как решать [геометрию](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488723) и [биологию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489971/181472)?
- Что делать, если бросил парень?
- Как придумать историю, чтобы иммигрировать в Голландию под видом сирийского беженца?
- Что делать, если с пацанами весь семестр бухали, а теперь отчисляют?

Баннер же ясно говорит, задай вопрос и тебе ответят. Вот я и задам.

---

Думаю, хорошо бы как-то уточнить, что вопрос должен быть по тематике сайта.

---

UPD: теперь с немецким акцентом!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что ж без ссылкок-то?)))

Comment: _Что делать, если с пацанами весь семестр бухали, а теперь отчисляют?_ - а что, так можно было???

Comment: @Qwertiy не сохранились)

Comment: @Grundy, вроде было что-то такое. Не верен. Но про отчисление точно было :)

Comment: Подразумевается, что попадающие на сайт люди, понимают что из себя представляет Stack Overflow. Если это не так, то, на мой взгляд, будет верно понять, почему так происходит и как этого избежать, а не перегружать баннер.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky согласен, что перегружать баннер не стоит.

Comment: @Qwertiy: одну добавил )

Answer (score 9):

Предлагаю набросать альтернативных текстов.

> ### Хочешь разобраться в программировании?
>
> ### Задавай вопрос!

> ### Интересно, как написать код лучше?
>
> ### Задавай вопрос!

> ### Это баг компилятора или фича языка?
>
> ### Задавай вопрос!

Comment: Особенно последнее мне нравится. :)

Comment: Отличные варианты! Я отправлю их ребятам, думаю, все согласятся их разместить!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Мне кажется, стоит прикрепить вопрос, чтобы участники с литературным талантом добавили ещё что-нибудь.

Comment: @VladD, а что, вопросы типа "Это баг компилятора или фича языка?" уже не будут закрывать?

Comment: @avp: Вроде ж у нас за такое не закрывали. Я не припомню.